# how to fix to show main domain when input subdomain in Magento?

Tags: magento2, url, domain, cpanel, subdomain

I cloned Magento project from main domain to subdomain in cPanel.
I fixed secure and unsecure URL in database.
But if I input subdomain URL, it show main domain URL.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to open up the core_config_data table. In the example below, the table is named mgql_core_config_table. You will need to change the URL to the new URL in the following two records:

> “web/unsecure/base_url”
>
> “web/secure/base_url”

Change the value section from http://main.com/ to http://subdomain.com/  in there.

Finally Clearing the cache: `bin/magento cache:clean`